# Can CloudFormation to create an AMI from a Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create an AWS CloudFormation template that creates an AMI from a snapshot?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? CloudFormation is normally used to create a stack of infrastructure, which you can later update or delete. Creating an AMI is an action rather than creating some infrastructure. Please Edit your question to provide more details of your use-case. For example, what do you intend doing with the AMI? Why does it have to be done via a CloudFormation template instead of via the console or a [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command?

Comment: Thanks replying John..

Comment: i want recover the instance if its failed in cluster via snapshot.
1.from snapshot - create --> AMI --> Using new AMI -> launch new instance
same as before it was there in the cluster.
plz  suggest -can we create AMI using snapshot of root device in CF .

Answer (score 0):

The [`AWS::EC2::Volume`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html#cfn-ec2-ebs-volume-snapshotid) resource will create an Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volume.

One of the parameters that the Volume resource takes is a **Snapshot ID**, which identifies the snapshot to use when creating the volume.

```
"NewVolume" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Volume",
   "Properties" : {
     "Size" : "100",
     "VolumeType" : "io1",
     "Iops" : "100",
     "SnapshotId" : "snap-abcd1234",
     "AvailabilityZone" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "AvailabilityZone" ] }
   }
}
```

This doesn't create an *AMI*, but it does create an EBS volume. You'll have to experiment to see whether this can be used as the boot volume on an instance.

See: [AWS::EC2::Volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html#cfn-ec2-ebs-volume-snapshotid)

Comment: Thanks John,
There are lot of stuff associated with my snapshot like ELB & gateways etc..
hence i wanted to keep all associated stuff as it is while creating new instance. plz suggest if its possible to CF  stack from sanpshot ID or not
if not what are the other possible ways.
thx

Comment: I'm not sure whether you could boot off a volume restored from a snapshot. The alternative, that will definitely work, is to script calls to the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or to write an app that calls the AWS APIs. They can be used to create an AMI from the snapshot, then boot off the AMI.